# Nifi 1.7 - PutHive3Streaming commit issues

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use Nifi 1.7 with Hive 3.0 and PutHive3Streaming processor. In my case, the records the records are getting transmitted to `Failed queue` without any `ERROR` messages on Nifi.

The Hive-metastore logs too have nothing significant to report.

Something interesting I noted in the nifi log trace is the stats: `records-written: 1,committed-transactions: 0`

Nifi log trace:

```
Closed streaming connection. Agent: NiFi PutHive3Streaming [1b137530-0166-1000-67c9-15cea37724a5] thread 59[Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] Stats: {records-written: 1, records-size: 0, committed-transactions: 0, aborted-transactions: 0, auto-flushes: 0, metastore-calls: 7 }
```

I built the PutHive3Streaming processors from support/nifi-1.7.x branch from [https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/support/nifi-1.7.x](http://github)

Is the 1.7 version and specifically the hive3.0 processors good to use in production?

Comment: Can you share more of the relevant logs? Are you saying there are no ERROR log messages related to this, nor bulletins being reported on the processor itself (in the UI)? Also maybe try the release-1.7.1 tag rather than the support branch.

Comment: I tried with release-1.7.1 tag and it is working without issues.